# Problemas para fechar comunicação com o Banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, jsp

Estou com algumas aplicações consumindo dados do banco de dados, mas de um tempo pra cá as aplicações não estão conseguindo fechar a conexão, quando eu dou um `conexao.close();` o Java fala que não pode fechar por que o `ResultSet` que esta logo a cima no bloco try já foi fechado.

Vejam abaixo meu código

```
    public ResultSet getHist(int ID) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement state = null;
    Connection conexao = null;
    try{
        conexao = FactoryConnection_MySQL.getConnection("base");
        state = conexao.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table where id = ?");
        state.setInt(1, ID);
        rs = state.executeQuery();            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(!rs.isClosed()){//aqui eu verifico se o rs ta fechado ou não
                System.out.println("Rs não fechado...");
                conexao.close();
            }else{
            System.out.println("Rs ja fechado!");
        }
        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
```

Segue o erro :

```
Informações:   Rs não fechado...false
Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:743)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6289)
    at org.apache.jsp.historico_jsp._jspService(historico_jsp.java:985)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [MySQL deixando conexões abertas por muito tempo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346798/28595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que você mude o código para usar o bloco try-with-resources.
Declare os seus recursos (`ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement` e `Connection`) desta forma, pois todas elas implementam atualmente a interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

Assim, você não precisará se preocupar em fechar os recursos manualmente.

Para entender o conceito e ver exemplos, veja em: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html